# In python os library, process was blocked

Tags: python

I am using `os.remove` in a `for` loop. Sometimes, the process was blocked, like a dead lock, but I'm not using a thread.

I want to know why process was blocked, and what can I do to prevent it?

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: I use suse linux 13.1

Answer (score 1):

The file you're deleting might be in use or requires administrative privileges to remove. You can use a subprocess to call you script as an administrator.

Comment: 1. The file is not in use.
2. My script run on "root" user.                     



Is subprocess don't care that using file, privilege?